# Strange BackboneJS Models

Tags: backbone.js

I'm looking through someone else's code and learning Backbone at the same time. This code supposedly uses Backbone but all the views have model's that are purposely set to null or just don't set model at all.

It is used some places in functions like `this.model.set("stuff")` though. It doesn't really match up to what I'm reading though so I'm wondering if someone could tell me what circumstances this would occur in. (Is BackboneJS just being used incorrectly? There are a ton of jQuery libraries which seem to be shoved into a Backbone structure)

Comment: There's not really enough to go on here. Maybe the app was originally just a pile of jQuery that was quickly converted to Backbone.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, I was just wondering whether or not this was a common "red flag" that people see often.